# TabView vs SegmentedBar

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I am creating SegmentedBar in native script. I am able to create segments but I am not able to add Label to segment view.

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
      <SegmentedBar>
          <SegmentedBar.items>

              <SegmentedBarItem title="Segment 1">
                  <SegmentedBarItem.view>                      
                      <Label text=" I am in segment bar 1"/>
                  </SegmentedBarItem.view>
              </SegmentedBarItem>

              <SegmentedBarItem title="Segment 2">
                  <SegmentedBarItem.view>
                    <Label text=" I am in segment bar 2"/>
                  </SegmentedBarItem.view>
              </SegmentedBarItem>

          </SegmentedBar.items>
      </SegmentedBar>
  </StackLayout>    
</Page>
```

What is the difference between SegmentedBar and TabView as both appear same.

Answer (score 1):

The Segmented bar is [described in a good way by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html):

> A segmented control is a horizontal control made of multiple segments,
>   each segment functioning as a discrete button.

So basically: A Segmented Bar is a couple of buttons (visually) connected to each other. Just think of them like buttons with a specific look.

A TabView on the other hand the tabs (the items you click) and a connected view to each tab.

What you're doing in your code is that you're trying to combine mechanics of the TabView with the SegmentedBar.

Take a look at these two code examples.

First, the SegmentedBar. Here is an example. When you click the "First", "Second" or "Third" button nothing will happen. To react on a button press you've to bind the `selectedIndex` to an [Observable object](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable/HOW-TO.html) property and do your logic in the on the [propertyChange event](https://docs.nativescript.org/events#propertychange-event).

```
<SegmentedBar selectedIndex="{{ selectedIndex }}">
    <SegmentedBar.items>
        <SegmentedBarItem title="First" />
        <SegmentedBarItem title="Second" />
        <SegmentedBarItem title="Third" />
    </SegmentedBar.items>
</SegmentedBar>
```

The TabView, on the other hand, consist of two things, the tabs themselves (the things you press) and a View connected to each tab. So when you click a tab the view gets changed.

```
 <TabView>
   <TabView.items>
     <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
       <TabViewItem.view>
          <Label text="Label in Tab1" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
     <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
       <TabViewItem.view>
          <Label text="Label in Tab2" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
   </TabView.items>
 </TabView>
```

These two components are used for different things. E.g. for filtering a list (show all mails, show only unread mails...) you usually use the segmented bar as you don't want to change the view - you want to change the *content* of the view. The TabView is used for when you actually want to display a whole new view.

Answer (score 0):

You may know the `<TabView>` is created keeping in mind to show different pages/views in single page/view. Thus, TabView is used mainly for navigating to different views.

The `SegmentedBar` is created for different purpose. This can be used in a view with different functionality for example you can categorize the contents/products as **Free**, **Paid**. You would want to show different product **features**, **services** on **Free view and Paid view**. Thus, you can use the `SegmentedBar` to show different options for the user.

So, now you know the difference between the `TabView` and the `SegmentedBar`.

The correct use of `SegmentedBar` is to use like this:

```
<SegmentedBar>
  <SegmentedBar.items>
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Free" />
    <SegmentedBarItem title="Paid" />
  </SegmentedBar.items>
</SegmentedBar>
```

To conclude, use `TabView` for navigating multiple pages in single page and use `SegmentedBar` for viewing different content in a single view.

Comment: What is the recommended way to  have a TabBar that has an extra "button" that does not navigate away from the current TabView but instead triggers an action (i.e. opens a modal)?

Comment: @lilbiscuit prevent the default behavior and open a model.