# Nativescript SegmentedBar propertyChangeEvent

Tags: nativescript

I have created a segmentedbar in Nativescript, but my changes are not picked up by propertyChangeEvent listener I've created. Can someone tell me what my mistake is?

Code for XML

```
<SegmentedBar row="1" colspan="3" class="toggles" selectedBackgroundColor="#B76769" selectedIndex="{{ bookingsObsSelectedIndex }}">
      <SegmentedBar.items>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Product"/>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Service" completed="false"/>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Total" completed="true"/>
      </SegmentedBar.items>
</SegmentedBar>
```

Binding my index to observable object and creating a propertychange event.

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var bookingsObsSelectedIndex = new observableModule.Observable();

bookingsObsSelectedIndex.on(observableModule.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function (propertyChangeData) {
    console.log("Property changed for bookingsObs, changed property name: = "+propertyChangeData.propertyName);
});
```

Sorry, I am new with Nativescript. Trying to follow steps specified [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986817/segmentedbar-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SO answer you are reading is a bit old and since then a `selectedIndexChanged` event was added to the `SegmentedBar`. So instead of using the `propertyChanged` event of the bound observable you can directly hook to the new event:

```
    <SegmentedBar row="1" colspan="3" class="toggles" selectedBackgroundColor="#B76769" 
selectedIndex="{{ bookingsObsSelectedIndex }}" selectedIndexChanged="segmentedBarIndexChanged">
          <SegmentedBar.items>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="Product"/>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="Service" completed="false"/>
                <SegmentedBarItem title="Total" completed="true"/>
          </SegmentedBar.items>
    </SegmentedBar>
```

And then in your page javascript to have something like:

```
function segmentedBarIndexChanged(args) {
    console.log("Tab selected: " + args.newIndex + ", old one is:" + args.oldIndex);
}
exports.segmentedBarIndexChanged = segmentedBarIndexChanged;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addEventListener` method instead `on` to handle on property change event. Your code should be something like this:

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
  <SegmentedBar  selectedIndex="{{ bookingsObsSelectedIndex }}">
      <SegmentedBar.items>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Product"/>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Service" completed="false"/>
            <SegmentedBarItem title="Total" completed="true"/>
      </SegmentedBar.items>
  </SegmentedBar>

  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**main-page.js**

```
var observable_1 = require("data/observable"); // Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml function navigatingTo(args) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = args.object;
    var newObservable = new observable_1.Observable();
    newObservable.set("bookingsObsSelectedIndex", 1);
    newObservable.addEventListener(observable_1.Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function (pcd) {
        console.log(pcd.eventName.toString() + " " + pcd.propertyName.toString() + " " + pcd.value.toString());
    });
    page.bindingContext = newObservable; } exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo;
```

In regard to that you could read more about the binding [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/bindings)

Comment: `on()` does the same thing as `addEventListener()` https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_data_observable_.observable.html#on