# Nativescript + Angular Segmented bar can't route to other components?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nativescript

I am trying to use a SegmentedBar to visualize 2 types of forms that are in a different components, if I remove the part with the routing to the components everything works fine and the bar itself visualizes, but with the routing part even the bar does not visualize and is just blank.

One of the components the other is similar:

```
<ScrollView>

    <StackLayout>

        <TextField [text]="first_name" hint="First Name" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <TextField [text]="last_name" hint="Last Name" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <TextField [text]="email" hint="Email" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <TextField [text]="company_name" hint="Company name" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <TextField [text]="company_position" hint="Position in company" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <Label text="Company size" class="purpish label-marg font-weight-bold"></Label>
        <ListPicker [items]="sizes"
                    [text]="company_size" class="p-15" ngDefaultControl>
        </ListPicker>

        <TextField [text]="company_resume" textWrap="true" hint="Company resume" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <TextField [text]="year_of_creation" hint="Year of creation of the company" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <Label text="Branch of the company" class="purpish label-marg font-weight-bold"></Label>
        <ListPicker [items]="branches"
                    [text]="branch_company" class="p-15" ngDefaultControl>
        </ListPicker>

        <Label text="Country" class="purpish label-marg font-weight-bold"></Label>
        <ListPicker [items]="countries" [text]="country" class="p-15" ngDefaultControl>
        </ListPicker>


        <TextField [text]="city" hint="City" class="purplish label-marg"></TextField>

        <Label text="You can add job opening in your profile" class="purpish" margin-left="20px"></Label>

    </StackLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

The SegmentedBar component xml/html:

```
<basictoolbar></basictoolbar>
<StackLayout>
   <SegmentedBar #sb [items]="navItems" selectedIndex="0" (selectedIndexChange)="navigate(sb.selectedIndex)">   

   </SegmentedBar>

   <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
</StackLayout>
```

And the ts:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { SegmentedBar, SegmentedBarItem } from "ui/segmented-bar";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ChangeDetectorRef,ApplicationRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'cvformpage',
    templateUrl: './components/cvformpage/cvformpage.component.html'
})

export class CvformpageComponent {

    public navItems: Array<SegmentedBarItem>;

        public constructor(private router: Router, private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef,private ref:ChangeDetectorRef) {
            this.navItems = [];           
            this.navItems.push(this.createSegmentedBarItem("Employer Form"));
            this.navItems.push(this.createSegmentedBarItem("Employee Form"));           


        }

        private createSegmentedBarItem(title: string): SegmentedBarItem {
            let item: SegmentedBarItem = new SegmentedBarItem();
            item.title = title;           
            return item;
        }

        public navigate(index: number) {
            switch(index) {
                case 0:
                    console.log("I am here");                    
                    this.router.navigate(["/employer-form"]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.router.navigate(["/employee-form"]);
                    break;
            }
        }

}
```

I tried it with console log and it gets inside the switch and inside the right case, but something get's messed up with the routing. I thank you in advance guys if someone can help me on the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem after sometime, I realized that `TabView` is the better way to go, anyway I tried `TabView` with routing on item change and it won't work. Because basically what happens:

**1. I render a page with the tabs**

**2.Then I try to route to another component**

**3. This confuses `nativescript`, because routing tries to change the whole page to another, while the concept of `TabView` or `SegmentedBar` is quite different and it supposes that the view should stay in the "scope" in other words it should be attached to the `TabView`, but instead it tries to "dominate"**

So the simple solution using `TabView` because of [TabView vs SegmentedBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986817/tabview-vs-segmentedbar) question is as simple as to put the component/view selectors of my components in the `tabview's` view like this:

```
   <basictoolbar></basictoolbar>

    <TabView #tabView  >
      <StackLayout *tabItem="{title:'Employer Form'}">
          <employer-form></employer-form>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout *tabItem="{title:'Employee Form'}">
          <employee-form></employee-form>
      </StackLayout>
    </TabView>
```